# How can I enroll in the Ubuntu Software Centre on behalf of my company?

Tags: software-center, paid-applications

The [FAQ](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/commercial-software-faqs/) says I "can enroll as an individual or on behalf of your company" but I didn't find any field where I can indicate that I want to enroll on behalf of my company. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sign-up to the app developer programme either as an individual or on behalf of your organisation.

If it's on the behalf of your organisation then you need their authorisation to do so. Essentially, the legal agreement asks you to vouch that you have the authority to sign-up for your organisation and bind them to the legal agreement. There's no box where you have to indicate this, it's all part of the terms and conditions.

Comment: I see. I read the Commercial software FAQs again and it says that "Following publishing of your application we’ll contact you for confirmation of your invoice details" so I guess that's when I'll tell you more about my company. Am I right?

Comment: Nicu - If we require further information from someone on payment details then we would contact them using the email in their registration.